# Binary latent representation

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, machine-learning-model, autoencoder, vae

I've been working on a problem where I got stuck at encoding my data into a binary latent representation, most of the methods out there aren't really working for my case.

I have input for the encoder like this : [1,2,3,2,4,1] => 24 bits
I want it encoded to 14 bits in latent space and it should be binary
and then decoded to match the input.

I tried to add a binary regularizer to my AE To enforce it to encode it to binary.

The issue is that It doesn't seem to encode or decode well and I'm wondering if anyone has any idea how to make the encoding decoding close to 90% or higher.